# Convertir dos llaves foraneas en una llave primaria en django

Tags: python, django-models

necesito saber como convertir dos llaves foraneas un una llave primaria en una nueva relacion. Tengo dos entidades(Equipo y Mision) que su tipo de relacion es ManyToMany, cree una nueva relacion(EquipoEnMision) que contiene dos llaves foraneas ademas de otros campos, lo que quiero hacer es convertir dichas llaves foraneas en primarias en la nueva relacion creada

```
from django.db import models
class Mision(models.Model):
   pais = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   recompensa = models.IntergerField()
class Equipo(models.Model):
   nombre = models.ChatField(max_length=50)
class EquipoEnMision(models.Model):
   id_equipo = models.ForeignKey(Equipo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
   id_mision = models.ForeignKey(Mision, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
   fecha = models.DateField()
```

Quiero determinar si lo anterior es la mejor manera de hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

si lo que quieres es una relación ManyToMany deberías utilizar dicho tipo de dato que es ManyToManyField.

Imaginando que una misión puede tener muchos equipos puedes usar:

```
class Mision(models.Model):
   pais = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   recompensa = models.IntergerField()

class Equipo(models.Model):
   nombre = models.ChatField(max_length=50)
   mision = models.ManyToManyField(Mision)
   fecha_asignacion = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Agregando el campo de fecha a equipo puedes saber cuando se le asigno.

En la función donde asignas las misiones a los equipos harías algo como:

```
equipo = Equipo.objects.get(pk=1)
equipo.fecha_asignacion = date.Today()
```

Con eso tienes la fecha de asignación de esa mision.

Para saber que misiones tiene el equipo puedes usar lo siguiente, imaginando que quiero saber las misiones del equipo 1

```
misiones = Equipo.objects.get(pk=1).mision.all()
```

Igual dejo la documentación por si quieres profundizar mas.

[Documentación de Django 4 sobre ManytoMany](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/)

Comment: Recuerda que la relacion EquipoEnMision posee un atributo extra que es la fecha, es por esa razon la duda que tengo. En tu respuesta no hay forma de poder acceder a la fecha

Comment: Actualizare la respuesta con otra propuesta